# Merging shapefiles in QGIS but getting error message

Tags: qgis

I am trying to merge multiple shapefiles into one so I can select all wetland polygons that intersect with this layer. For my purposes, I don't care about the attributes as long as I have the polygon.

As I try to merge the files I get an error message saying: "SARA_Statu in field X has different data type than in other layers (Integer64 instead of String)."

So from my understanding it wont merge attributes together because one is an integer data type in one shapefile and it is string in another. Is there a quick work around to merging these files without tweaking with the attributes? For my purposes, I just want the polygon and I don't care about the attributes.

Comment: You have fields named the same, with different types, in multiple inputs. You can rename, change data type or drop them using Refactor fields

Answer (score 2):

Since you don't care about the attributes, you can delete them.  That way there will be no data type conflict.  To do this, open each shapefile's attribute table and click the *Edit* button.  Then click the *Delete Field* button.  Select all of the fields that you don't want (gotta keep the ObjectID field however!) and click Ok.  Then save your edits and close the edit session.  Voila, you're now ready to merge!

If you have lots of shapefiles, consider using the *Drop Fields* tool in batch mode. This might be faster than the manual editing method described above.